# In AngularJS, how to use multipart/related to POST a JSON object and a File in one request

Tags: angularjs

I need to send a POST request with a JSON object and a File in the same request with Content-Type: multipart/related. I could use Content-Type: multipart/form-data, but requirement asks for Content-Type: multipart/related.

Sample Request would be:

Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=Example_boundary_37464
Content-Length: 2001
...
--Example_boundary_37464
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Description: json

{
    "name": "Test123",
    "firstname": "TestFirstName",
    "lastname": "TestLastName"
}

--Example_boundary_37464
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: document

VGhlIFBsZWRnZSBvZiBBbGxlZ2lhbmNlIHRvIHRoZSBGbGFnOiCTSSBwbGVkZ2UgYWxsZWdpYW5j
ZSB0byB0aGUgRmxhZyBvZiB0aGUgVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcyBvZiBBbWVyaWNhLCBhbmQgdG8gdGhl

--Example_boundary_37464

Any help would be greatly appreciated.